# Extracting domain and subdomain using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, subdomain

I just have a simple url and I want to extract subdomain and domain name from url using regular expression (not using split function). Suppose the url is http://www.example.google.com/file.html, then it should alert something like:

```
"Domain: google.com, Subdomain: example"
```

I want to do this using only javascript.

Comment: In your url, I do not think you want the www. Or do you? dun dun

Comment: What should happen to: `http://www.google.co.uk/` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is non-trivial (see http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/46/parsing-urls-with-regular-expressions-and-the-regex-object for example, which doesn't even address splitting the authority section.)

You will at least need a list of all top-level domains to do this correctly.

EDIT: edge case examples you need to think of:

- google.com
- google.co.uk
- sergey.brin@google.com